# Sort MYSQL Results By Occurrence Priority Using PHP Or SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I use the php script below to query mysql and to display:

```
$sql1 = $con->prepare("SELECT item FROM product WHERE item LIKE ?");
$q = '%' . $q . '%';
$sql1->bind_param("s", $q);
$sql1->execute();
$sql1->bind_result($item);

while ($sql1->fetch()) {          
echo "<div>$item</div>
```

Let say search $q = 'test tube'
The result did come out like this:

```
brush for test tube
test tube glass
test tube plastic
```

(This is logic since the items are indexed alphabetically in mysql)

But I after I get result array from query, I want to use PHP to sort it again by giving priority first to which ever item that meets the search keyword at the front most.

I expect the result like this:

```
test tube glass
test tube plastic
brush for test tube
```

How can I do that? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just ORDER BY [INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)(item, ?).

Comment: It returns the index the substring is found at; while it is typically used for primitive string parsing, it should work fine for your needs as well. Just don't forget your query has an extra parameter now.

Comment: Yes I got it. Accept your answer.